# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server when run as flyway migration

Tags: mysql, jpa, flyway

in IntelliJ I created DDL script to add flyway and migrate schema to remote db. However there is some issue in syntax. **When I run the script from console everything seems to be fine and tables are created. If I run exactly the same script as flyway migration there is error :**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uniqueidentifier not null, created_ts date, last_updated_ts date, data longblob,' at line 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
```

here's my script

```
create table payment_plan
(
    ID varchar(256) not null
        primary key,
    PLAN_TYPE varchar(256) null,
    PRICE varchar(64) null,
    LAST_UPDATED_TS date null,
    MAX_PAGES int null,
    PAGES_MAX int null,
    CREATED_TS date null
);

create table representative
(
    ID varchar(256) not null
        primary key,
    NAME varchar(256) null,
    EMAIL varchar(64) null,
    PHONE_NUMBER varchar(64) null,
    CREATED_TS date null,
    LAST_UPDATED_TS date null
);

create table url
(
    ID varchar(256) not null
        primary key,
    ORIGINAL_URL varchar(256) null,
    SHORT_LINK varchar(64) null,
    EXPIRATION_DATE date null,
    LAST_UPDATED_TS date null,
    CREATED_TS date null
);

create table user
(
    ID varchar(256) not null
        primary key,
    NAME varchar(45) null,
    EMAIL varchar(45) null,
    IMAGE_URL varchar(256) null,
    EMAIL_VERIFIED tinyint null,
    PROVIDER varchar(45) null,
    PROVIDER_ID varchar(45) null,
    LAST_UPDATED_TS datetime null,
    PASSWORD varchar(45) null,
    BIRTH_DATE date null,
    PHONE_NUMBER varchar(64) null,
    ADDRESS varchar(256) null,
    POST_CODE varchar(64) null,
    COUNTRY varchar(64) null,
    CITY varchar(64) null,
    PAYMENT_PLAN_ID varchar(64) default '0' null,
    STATUS varchar(64) default '0' null,
    RESET_URL_ID varchar(64) null,
    CONFIRMED tinyint(1) default 0 null,
    NEXT_ACTION_DATE date null,
    CREATED_TS date null,
    FREQUENCY int default 0 null,
    REPRESENTATIVE_NAME varchar(256) null,
    REPRESENTATIVE_EMAIL varchar(64) null,
    REPRESENTATIVE_PHONE_NUMBER varchar(64) null,
    constraint user_ibfk_1
        foreign key (PAYMENT_PLAN_ID) references payment_plan (ID),
    constraint user_ibfk_2
        foreign key (RESET_URL_ID) references url (ID)
);

create table page
(
    ID varchar(256) not null
        primary key,
    USER_ID varchar(256) null,
    CONTENT longtext null,
    LAST_UPDATED_TS date null,
    ADDRESSEE_NAME varchar(64) null,
    ADDRESSEE_MAIL varchar(64) null,
    ADDRESSEE_PHONE varchar(64) null,
    CREATED_TS date null,
    VIDEO_NAME varchar(256) null,
    constraint page_ibfk_1
        foreign key (USER_ID) references user (ID)
            on delete cascade
);

create index USER_ID
    on page (USER_ID);

create index PAYMENT_PLAN
    on user (PAYMENT_PLAN_ID);

create index RESET_URL_ID
    on user (RESET_URL_ID);
```

There're no comas at the end of the create table query , no "type" word , no doubles ... no idea whats wrong.

here's properties file:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxx"
    user: xxx
    password: xxx
    enabled: true
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  datasource:
    hikari:
      jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxx
      username: xxx
      password: xxx
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` report when you run it in the query tool?

Comment: it reports 8.0.23

Comment: The Java exception mentions MySQL got confused at the data type `uniqueidentifier`, but that word does not appear in the SQL example you posted. Either Flyway is transforming the syntax to Microsoft SQL Server's flavor of SQL syntax, or else you posted the wrong SQL script.

Comment: So the script is 100% correct.   Tbh I dont even know if this is flyway issue - I removed flyway , deleted migration folder but this error still appears - app starts but db is empty. But if I run script from console everything is ok.

Comment: Is it the Spring Boot application? If yes, please share the application.properties in use. What database is it?

Comment: Yes, SB app. application.properties added